# Make an application stay on a single workspace while it's launching

Tags: linux, gnome, launch, workspace

There's a thing with the `workspaces` and launching of applications with several Linux distros that has bothered me for some time now. When you start an application that takes a while to launch, and say you are on `Workspace 1`, and then change over to `Workspace 2` to do something else while the app is launching, then as soon as the application is done loading, or at least the window frame is generated, it pops up on on your current `workspace`, in front of whatever window you were just working in. I find this behavior pretty annoying (particularly on low performance machines where it usually takes a noticeable amount of time to launch anything), not just because of the interruption, but also because I then always have to manually move the application back to whichever `workspace` I actually wanted to have it in.

I'd much prefer it if I could launch the application in one workspace, and it would just stay there throughout its entire launching phase, so that I can come back to it a few moments later when it's finished loading, and I've finished whatever I else I was doing.

To me this seems to be pretty universal behavior across several linux distributions (Debian and Ubuntu), albeit I've mainly been using `Gnome 2` and `XFCE` where the `Window Managers` are concerned. I found a very similar topic [here](https://superuser.com/questions/232042/ubuntu-gnome-open-an-application-in-a-specific-workspace):

But it didn't provide any satisfying answer (and it was a year ago). Can this be fixed/adjusted in XFCE and/or Gnome2 somehow? If not, is there any (lightweight) window manager that handles this the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

Application is not be able to do that. It's window manager job to decide. But once you open one app it should stay where you left it and usually all further windows opened by that application should also end on the same workspace. So you either need to instruct window manager ("how" depends on what WM you use) or use tools like [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

"once you open one app it should stay where you left it" -- even while the application is still launching, before even the frame for the app has been generated?

Essentially I want the window manager to remember which workspace I was in when I gave the command to launch a given application, and then directly put the window (as soon as it's available) into that workspace, regardless of which workspace I'm currently in at that point in time.